# Disable a button on a specific drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Trying to work out a small issue with dojo, where if the value of myCode equals selCode (Value selected from dropdown)
the button needs to be disabled. Where am I going wrong here? 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aman/BmSjb/1/)

```
var myCode = "CC";

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#codes'), "onchange", function(evt) {
        var selCode = this.val();
        if (selCode == myCode) {
            dojo.attr('#submit', disabled);
        }
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    });
});
```

---

```
<select name="codes" id="codes" class="codes">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Below</option>
    <option value="AA">AA</option>
    <option value="BB">BB</option>
    <option value="CC">CC</option>
    <option value="DD">DD</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know anything about Dojo, but is sure looks like you're trying to use jQuery methods `.val()` and `.attr()`, unless Dojo has the same methods. (I couldn't find docs for them.)

Abandoning the library code for the native API would work like this:

```
var myCode="CC"; 

dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
     dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#codes'), "onchange", function(evt) {
         var selCode = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value;
         if(selCode == myCode){
             document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
         }
         dojo.stopEvent(evt);
     });
 });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BmSjb/21/

---

**EDIT:** Based on the comment below, you want it to toggle based on matching selection.

```
var myCode = "CC";

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#codes'), "onchange", function(evt) {
        var selCode = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = (selCode == myCode);
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BmSjb/32/

Now the `.disabled` property will be set to the result of `selCode == myCode`, so when `true` it will be disabled. When `false`, enabled.

Comment: One problem, It keeps the button disabled even when drop down value is changed back to something else

Comment: @t0mcat: This is because it doesn't know that you want to change it back. I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:
1. Dojo doesn't use CSS selectors like that. Don't use a #.
2. The attr function takes three params (when doing what you want to do): id/dojoObj, attr name, attr value.

```
var myCode="CC";    
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
   dojo.connect(dojo.byId('codes'), "onchange", function(evt) {
      if(this.value == myCode){
         dojo.attr('submit', 'disabled', 'disabled');
      }
      dojo.stopEvent(evt);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I didnt see your answer before. I have worked with jQuery.. hence the habit of CSS selectors :)

Comment: +1 I don't know a thing about Dojo, so I gave a more native answer. This would be more correct since it seems that the original selector is returning the `window` instead of the `select` element.

Comment: No worries. I was a bit slow getting it submitted. I prefer jQuery to all other frameworks myself. My Dojo experience is rather limited. The things you learn maintaining legacy apps...

Comment: Josh, one question. Does a function has to go under addOnLoad? How to write the same function on its own?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but basically the answer is yes, most of the time. Passing a function to addOnLoad will cause it to be executed on page load. So if you are going to connect a function to an event on an element, you nearly always want this to happen during the onload. Its basically analogous to jQuery's document on ready.

Comment: What I am trying to ask was, Should I call this function through addOnLoad or onChange event of the dropdown. Which makes more sense?

Comment: Binding events in onload is the best practice. So the above example is the preferred technique.